# Sent packets via PyOSC

Tags: python, packet, osc

I am trying to send data from an EEG headset via OSC. I can print the data and I am also able to send independent OSC messages via OSCClient but I can't manage to sent the whole packet via OSC:

```
 from OSC import OSCClient, OSCMessage # Import Open Sound Control    Module
from emokit.emotiv import Emotiv # Import EmoKit

client = OSCClient()
client.connect( ("localhost", 9098) )



if __name__ == "__main__":
with Emotiv(display_output=True, verbose=True, write=True) as    headset:
    while True:
        packet = headset.dequeue()
        client.send( OSCMessage("/pack", packet)
        if packet is not None:
              print("Gyro - X:{x_position} Y:{y_position}".format(x_position=packet.sensors['X']['value'],
                                                                y_position=packet.sensors['Y']['value']))
```

Comment: I edited parts of your code but indentation of the `if __name__ == ...` part is still wrong and won't run. Could you [edit] it, so it will be copy-and-paste-able?

Comment: Thanks for your edit. The copied the wrong part from the emokit example, for the printing works great, but still you are right